# Type hinting Promise response with 2 possible values

Tags: typescript, type-hinting

I have the following TypeScript function definition:

```
export const handler = async (): Promise<LambdaOutput | DCDErrorResponse> => {
 const result1: Promise<LambdaOutput> = await func1();
 const result2: Promise<DCDErrorResponse> = await func2();

 return someMagicalCondition() ? result1 : result2;
};
```

Another piece of code imports `handler()` and executes it:

```
const result = await handler();
console.log(result.upload); // <-- fail to access attributes, available in the LambdaOutput type but not in the other possible return type of the Promise
```

The problem is, whenever I try to access result.upload in the last example (a property, that's only available in LambdaOutput and not in DCDErrorResponse), the TypeScript compiler complains with:

> TS2339: Property 'upload' does not exist on type 'LambdaOutput | DCDErrorResponse'.   Property 'upload' does not exist on type 'DCDErrorResponse'.

Answer (score 2):

Since your return value could be multiple data types, you have to check to make sure it's the type you really want before you start treating like one of those type. In this case, you should be able to check if that property exists. Then Typescript can lock in the proper type in that branch of code.

```
const result = await handler();
if ('upload' in result) {
   // Typescript knows result is a LambdaOutput here
   console.log(result.upload);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwAspVgIQYAKASgC54BveZABwhymDoHJEccv4AX3gAfBvBwYC5OgEYATAGYhAWABQ6qAGcAnuiRpMufLxzUG6+PDB4tGeHC3II9gLyFipctQDcl+FiI8BRcLGwcAlj4js4YVBZqVlYA9MnwACo6zCBaYDBYzPYA1qg4AO5aDjmxAZVQ8AAyUAC2AEbAUADyyBjMPYTkIP5WNqhaOGQAdGwA5hQxLpNh7MBUfomqGhup8ACiAB7ZmPDE8OQwODAANEysK-DMF9kwGDrwzVBvpfYg+1h2-lG4yms3m1UWyw4VHUgnUQA)

Comment: I was looking for a more elegant solution. One that doesn't rely on runtime checks. It will have to suffice thought. Thanks!

Comment: Your function is typed to require runtime checks. You may only use common properties of a union, unless you check at runtime.